# Google Chrome: CSS translate inside foreignObject inside SVG

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have this html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Translate test</title>
<body>

<style>
    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>

<svg style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <g transform="translate(100, 100)">
        <foreignObject width="200"
                       height="200">
            <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                 style="height: 100%; background: pink; transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);">
            </div>
        </foreignObject>
    </g>
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Applying `translate3d` to the inner div makes it ignore the translate value of its parent `<g>` and places it at the top left. On the other hand replacing `translate3d` with a `translate(0, 0)` yields a more expected result (doesn't move it). Firefox behaves more predictably though and displays the div at (100, 100) in both cases.

The question is: which is the correct behavior (and why)?

A bonus question: how do I make the translates stack in the above example? The real html that I have in my app is produced by a combination of some 3rd party libraries, and those translate values are dynamic.